# Using the null propagation operator fails in gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp, null-propagation-operator

I have a JS expression containing the *null propagation operator* but this fails when applying the gulp job to minify the JS.
Does anyone knows how to keep that syntax (without doing if/else or using *ternary operator* (expression ? true : false) ?

My expression

```
let tableTitle = $(config.$table[0])?.siblings('.title-section')[0]?.innerText;
```

The gulp error:

```
TypeError in plugin "gulp-minify"
Message: dev\js\app_delivery.js
Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined (line: undefined, col: undefined, pos: undefined
Details:
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
```

My gulp task causing error :

```
gulp.task('JS-libs', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.modules.JS.libs)
    .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
    .pipe(minifyJS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.path.dest.rootJS))
});
```

The minifyJS function:

```
function minifyJS() {
    return gulpMinifyJS({
        ext:{
            src: '.js',
            min:'.min.js'
        }
    });
}
```

And my package.json config regarding gulp :

```
"gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-minify": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-remove-logging": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11"
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to have the benefit of no error on gulp AND one expression that doesn't crash when the HTML dom element being searched for isn't found :

```
try {
            let tableTitle = $(config.$table[0]).siblings('.title-section')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            ...
        }
        catch(error) {
            ...
            console.error(error);
        }
```

However, if someone knows how to answer to my initial question, I'll appreciate very much.